# Using Numpy.linalg in c++

Tags: python, c++, numpy

I am currently trying to optimise some code I wrote in python by rewriting it as a c++ extension. The code uses, however, not just ndarrays but also the numpy.linalg library for finding a matrix inverse. I found how I can use ndarrays in my extension, but was not able to find anything about how I can still use the numpy.linalg library. Is there any way to do this or do I have to call BLAS/etc. or even write my own function for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In C++ use Eigen++.

Comment: It seems quite hard to access NumPy C routines directly. If you look at [`umath_linalg.c.src`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.16.0/numpy/linalg/umath_linalg.c.src), it is a long file of templated C code that gets expanded later to cover different data types for each function. In the case of [`inv`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.16.0/numpy/linalg/umath_linalg.c.src#L1693-L1725), the [directives above](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.16.0/numpy/linalg/umath_linalg.c.src#L1555-L1561) suggest the relevant LAPACK functions are `sgesv`, `dgesv`, `cgesv` and `zgesv`.